# Getting the current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, getdate

I searched but wasn't able to find the way to get the date in this format (DD.MM.YYYY)
Help me please change this request:

```
DECLARE @date datetime
set @date = '01.05.2016'
SELECT [User], cast(DATEADD(SECOND, sum(datediff(DAY, @date,[Start])),@date) as date)'Date'
      ,cast(DATEADD(SECOND, sum(datediff(SECOND, '00:00:00',[Period])),'00:00:00') as time)'Total time'
  FROM [Table].[TableAction]
  where
   [Start] >= @date+'00:00:00' and [Start] <= @date+'23:59:59'
   group by [USER]
```

Comment: what did you try, did you google the problem, it is common sense. we are not here to do your homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to store the datetime in datetime format in the database and whenever you need the data you can access it and format it according to your need.

```
 DECLARE @Currentdate DATETIME;
 SET @Currentdate=GETDATE();   -- Store cuurent date into variable
```

And then when you want to display it use the below to format it as dd.MM.YYYY

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),104);  -- format the @Currentdate to the required format.
```

**FORMAT** works only in **SQL Server 2012+**. If your database is SQL server 2008 or 2005 FORMAT doesn't work.In that case, you can go for the `CONVERT` function.

So, If your database is above **SQL SERVER 2012**, you can go for **FORMAT** as suggested by [Tschallacka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356107/tschallacka)

```
DECLARE @Currentdate DATETIME=GETDATE(); -- Store cuurent date into variable
```

And then when you want to display it use the below to format it as dd.MM.YYYY

```
SELECT FORMAT(@Currentdate,'dd.MM.yyyy')  -- format the @Currentdate to the required format.
```

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @date datetime set @date = GETDATE()
```

Now to output it, you need to "Format" it.

```
select FORMAT (@date,'MM.dd.yy') as date
```

[image]