# SQL Query to get date

Tags: sql

How can I change this for TODAY? I'm making `@Hist_date` as `date` however it needs to be for today.
I have tried `GETDATE` abd I think I'm coding it wrong

```
(@HIST_DATE DATE)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the current date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383915/getting-the-current-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

use select.

```
declare @HIST_DATE date

select @HIST_DATE = GETDATE()
```